# Routing several layers deep through VPN

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, static-routes

So I've got a server at work which runs its own local subnet. I can vpn in, but have to setup a route to the network this machine is on to access it. I'm looking to natively access the second subnet. Everything is Linux (Ubuntu, Debian and embedded stuff). Here are details:

1. I start my vpn and get an IP on 192.168.100.0
2. I set a route to the network my server is on: 192.168.2.0; I can now
   ssh into the server and access the third subnet but this is very
   slow doing anything graphical
3. The third subnet, 192.168.0.0 is exclusively accessible on the
   server on eth2
4. So starting with 192.168.100.0, I set a route to natively access
   192.168.2.0. My server then controls 192.168.0.0.

Is there a way (there must be) to route or tunnel into that machine and locally ping or bring up webpages on 192.168.0.0?

So I (at home, 192.168.1.0) --> VPN (192.168.100.0) --> route to server's network (192.168.2.0) --> route to server's subnet on eth2 (192.168.0.0)?

I tried setting up nat rules but to no avail... machines on the final subnet can see the outside world, but I can't see in:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth2 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Thanks!